# Dynamic data-attribute in Blade

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade, custom-data-attribute

There is a subview named "x.blade.php" like this:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" class="star" data-index = "5"  data-type="" /><label for="star5" title="5 star"></label>
</div>
```

and then this subview is included in the main view by this code:

```
@include('x', ['type' => "file"])
```

The main goal is that I want to make "data-type" attribute in input tag in subview, dynamic and specify it by this part in @include

> ['type' => "file"]

I want it to be "file" type or "article" type.
e.g. => data-type="file"   or  data-type="article"
but this code does not work properly.

Is there a way to set data-* attribute in @include of blade template?

Any hint is appreciated,

Answer (score 2):

The solution is just using a double curly brace for $type variable just like below:

```
<input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" class="star" data-index = "1" data-type="{{$type}}"/>
```

Then the variable value is passed in data-type attribute.

Hope it helps someone,